# Second derivatives test - Finding unknown constants

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, constants

With the shape given by equation $Az = Bx^m + Cy^n − Dx − Ey + 14$ where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are measured in meters. If you are standing at location $(10, 30, 40)$, by performing second derivatives test, identify
$A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $m$ and $n$ such that $(10, 30, 40)$ is local maximum.

May I know how to identify all those constants?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.StackExchange. Have a look at [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) about asking a good question so that the community of users can help you.

Comment: And here's a [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial, to typeset mathematical expressions on this site and elsewhere.